# hide and show doesn't work with hover()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can see the hover() is working but it doesn't hide and show the contact_numbers class? What's wrong in my code?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#hdCallUs").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.contact_numbers').show();
    console.log('in')
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.contact_numbers').remove()
    console.log('out')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="hdCallUs">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
  <span class="call_txt">Call Us Now</span>

  <div class="contact_numbers">
    <li>999</li>
    <li>888</li>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: You have got invalid html inside the div.

Answer (score 2):

because of wrong `Dom` structure  in your html

`<ul>` is missing inside  `<div class="contact_numbers">`  how can a `<li>` start without `<ul>`

and in your question you write 
**hide and show doesn't work with hover()?** than why `.remove()` in your code
if you want to hide your element use `.hide()` see my code

```js
$(function() {
  $("#hdCallUs").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.contact_numbers').show();
    console.log($(this).find('.contact_numbers'))
  }, function() {
    //$(this).find('.contact_numbers').remove() // this will remove element 
   $(this).find('.contact_numbers').hide() // this will hide
    console.log('out')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="hdCallUs">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
  <span class="call_txt">Call Us Now</span>

  <div class="contact_numbers">
      <ul>
    <li>999</li>
    <li>888</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is broken, you are missing `<ul>` tag. Try this code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#hdCallUs").hover(function() {
    $('.contact_numbers').show(); <!-- changed this -->
  }, function() {
    $('.contact_numbers').hide()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="hdCallUs">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
  <span class="call_txt">Call Us Now</span>

  <div class="contact_numbers" style="display:none">
  <ul>  <!-- added this -->
    <li>999</li>
    <li>888</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are removing the element on `hover out`.

```
$(this).find('.contact_numbers').remove();
```

Is it expected? To hide element change this to:

```
$(this).find('.contact_numbers').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the structure of your html (li inside a div without ul?) but you can achieve this without javascript and just css like this:

```
.contact_numbers{
   display: none;
}

#hdCallUs:hover .contact_numbers{
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong html markup in your body which is **rendered differently** as compared to what you expect. Below is the rendered html:

```
<ul>
    <li id="hdCallUs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
 <span class="call_txt">Call Us Now</span>

        <div class="contact_numbers"></div>
    </li>
    <li>999</li>
    <li>888</li>
</ul>
```

So clearly the `.contact_numbers` div doesn't have anything to `hide` and `show` and probably this is the reason why you are not getting expected results. Correct your html and then try.

You can check the rendered html in the console in this demo
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/929/

Make sure you use `.hide()` and `.show()` or `.toggle()` as in this demo:
Demo with correct markup: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/930/

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#hdCallUs").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.contact_numbers').show();
        console.log('in', $(this).find('.contact_numbers'))
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.contact_numbers').hide()
        console.log('out', $(this).find('.contact_numbers'))
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li id="hdCallUs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
 <span class="call_txt">Call Us Now</span>

        <div class="contact_numbers">
            <ul>
                <li>999</li>
                <li>888</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have invalid `html`. You have to wrap your second level `li`s inside `ul`. `li` cannot have `li`s as its children and also, `display:none;` to your contact_numbers + do not `remove` it on hover out, instead just `hide` it. `remove` removes it permanently from `DOM`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#hdCallUs").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.contact_numbers').show();
    console.log('in')
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.contact_numbers').hide()
    console.log('out')
  });
});
```

```css
.contact_numbers{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="hdCallUs">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
  <span class="call_txt">Call Us Now</span>

  <div class="contact_numbers">
    <ul>
      <li>999</li>
      <li>888</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```